# SynchronousOnlyOperation from celery task using gevent execution pool

Tags: django, celery, python-asyncio, gevent

Given celery running with these options:

```
celery -A openwisp2 worker -l info --pool=gevent --concurrency=15 -Ofair
```

Given this [celery task from openwisp-monitoring](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-monitoring/blob/b327608e44d075d9cbb8a5112b3fada0ee22832c/openwisp_monitoring/check/tasks.py#L37-L50):

```
@shared_task
def perform_check(uuid):
    """
    Retrieves check according to the passed UUID
    and calls ``check.perform_check()``
    """
    try:
        check = get_check_model().objects.get(pk=uuid)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        logger.warning(f'The check with uuid {uuid} has been deleted')
        return
    result = check.perform_check()
    if settings.DEBUG:  # pragma: nocover
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Most of the time the task works, but some times (usually with bursts), the following exception is generated:

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Full stack trace:

```
SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "openwisp_monitoring/check/tasks.py", line 44, in perform_check
    check = get_check_model().objects.get(pk=uuid)
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1154, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
```

I do not fully understand why this is happening.

Let's recap, please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. with this configuration, celery can execute tasks in parallel, this parallelization is performed by gevent using an asyncio event loop
2. gevent then calls each task, using the same thread
3. the tasks are not designed to be asynchronous, they use plain sync code, these tasks perform DB queries and network requests
4. django has an `async_unsafe` decorator with which database operations are decorated, this decorator checks if the event loop is running and in that case it raises a `SynchronousOnlyOperation`

**But why isn't this exception raised in 100% of cases but only in a minority of cases?**

Those tasks are indeed working, I can see it because they produce the collection of chart data which is displayed normally, or they produce changes of status in the device model (eg: ok to critical).

Is it a bug in OpenWISP Monitoring, a misconfiguration or a bug in Django?

It looks like the event loop is not being used in Django, yet Django is raising this exception even though it does not concern it. This could be a bug, but would like to hear the opinion of experts on the subject before filing a bug report.

I thought that a possible quick solution may be to set the env variable `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` but only in the celery process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's just taking too much time occasionally, which is the entire point of using `await` in blocking calls, db calls being one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out my assumptions were wrong and I was using code which was not greenlet safe with gevent.

Since rewriting the code to be greenlet safe for now was not an option, I switched back to prefork.

Comment: well, I'm trying to configure `gevent` for I/O bound tasks. Could you give an example of "not greenlet safe" code or situation? Thanks.

Comment: @Paolo it depends on the libraries you're using, in my case I was using Django, which is relying on a lot of libraries which are not greenlet compatible.

Comment: I'm also using Django,  how can I determine if my libraries are not greenlet compatible?

Comment: @bearcat, the same reply I gave to Paolo above applies to you as well.

Comment: @nemesisdesign Thanks. I tried the gevent monkey patch and it seems to work for me so far.  I have probably not exercised all the libraries my django configuration is using, so there is likely still some risk.   I was looking for some way to determine if a library was greenlet compatible outside of running it in the django configuration.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that if you use Django, the only acceptable execution poll for celery worker out of the box is prefork? And other polls are not recommended for Django?

Comment: Async support in Django has been improving so I do not know if other pools are not recommended for your own use case, you have to investigate and find out on your own.
For this question I had asked, in my case, I cannot use greenlets without rewriting and retesting part of the OpenWISP code. For your own application we cannot know as we are not fortune tellers.