# SynchronousOnlyOperation from celery task using gevent execution pool on django orm

Tags: django, celery, gunicorn, django-orm, gevent

I found this question that describes exactly what happens to my software, but I haven't found any answers to this problem.

[SynchronousOnlyOperation from celery task using gevent execution pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326908/synchronousonlyoperation-from-celery-task-using-gevent-execution-pool)

is there any update on how to use gevent and celery in combination with django orm? I've opened quite a few issues from all sides but I'm not getting replies.

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/synchronousonlyoperation-from-celery-task-using-gevent-execution-pool/21105

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/synchronousonlyoperation-django-gunicorn-gevent/21182

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8262

https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1955

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/3000

this didn't help, celery already perform monkey.patch_all() on -p gevent
monkey.patch_all() and https://github.com/psycopg/psycogreen